Filebeat Helm chart to forward logs to Logstash
I need to deploy filebeat (filebeat-6.6.2)  as daemonset in AKS cluster and forward the logs to the Logstash server.
The official filebeat helm chart (https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/filebeat/values.yaml) sends the logs to Elastic search by default. But my requirement is to push the logs to the Logstash server instead of Elastic search and I don't find the configuration related to Logstash in the documentation.
Can you guide me or any pointers please.
Thanks in Advance.

The configuration is just Filebeat yaml, not specific to Helm https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html
